# Find the integer part of $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2016}+\frac{1}{2017}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2023}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is

Find the integer part of $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2016}+\frac{1}{2017}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2023}}$.
I tried to solve it by using harmonic progression but it is not working.

Kindly solve this question.

Comment: If you want math to display correctly enclose it in dollar signs. Also for the question what is the "trivial" lower/upper bound of $\frac1{2016}+\cdots+\frac1{2023}$?

Comment: Sorry for this error

Comment: My first time trying

Comment: @kingW3 can you explain what you are trying to tell. I don't get you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's observe the very trivial bound

\begin{align*}
 &\frac{8}{2023} < \sum_{k = 0}^{7} \frac{1}{2016 + k} < \frac{8}{2016}\\
 \implies & \frac{2023}{8} > \frac{1}{\sum_{k = 0}^{7} \frac{1}{2016 + k}} > \frac{2016}{8}
\end{align*}
Now we have that $~\dfrac{2016}{8} = 252$, and, $~\dfrac{2023}{8} = 252 + \dfrac{7}{8} < 253$.

Hence,
$$ \Bigg\lfloor \frac{1}{\sum_{k = 0}^{7} \frac{1}{2016 + k}} \Bigg\rfloor = 252 $$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*
$$
\frac{8}{2023} < \frac{1}{2016}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2023} < \frac{8}{2016} 
$$

Comment: Can you explain it more. I couldn't understand

Comment: @Astudiousstudent, how many terms in the sum? what is the smallest term? what is the largest term?

Comment: How can you say that $\frac{8}{2023}$ is less than the sum?